# Why PlotLegends doesn't give the legends ？

Tags: plotting

I am using Mathematica 9. The problem I have is with plotlengends, in particular,

```
g2 = ListPlot[{{2, 1}, {3, 4}, {3.5, 4.2}, {4, 6}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Dashing[Large]}, PlotLegends -> {"Dashed"}, 
  Joined -> True];
g1 = ListPlot[{{2, 1}, {3, 4}, {3.5, 4.2}, {4, 6}, {4.5, 6.6}, {5, 
    7}, {6, 9}, {8, 11}}, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {Dotted}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Dot"}];
Show[g1, g2]
```

[image]

As you can see, the problem is that looking at this lengends, there is no way you can tell which curve coresponds to which one in the legends (for instance, is the dash curve coresponds to the top legend or the bottom legend?). Changing the color will not work because this plot has to be in black and white only. Please help.

Comment: Works perfectly with me: "10.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 29, 2014)"

Comment: Sorry, it is matehamtica 9

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As noted by Eldo, this works out of the box on Mathematica 10.
On Mathematica 9 [`LineLegend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineLegend.html) does the trick:

```
data2 = {{2, 1}, {3, 4}, {3.5, 4.2}, {4, 6}};
data1 = {{2, 1}, {3, 4}, {3.5, 4.2}, {4, 6}, {4.5, 6.6}, {5, 7}, {6, 9}, {8, 11}};

ListPlot[
 {data1, data2}, 
 Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {Dotted, Dashing[Large]}, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{Dotted, Dashing[Large]}, {"Dot", "Dashed"}]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

This works with both versions:

```
g2 = ListPlot[{{2, 1}, {3, 4}, {3.5, 4.2}, {4, 6}}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Dashing[Large]}, Joined -> True];

g1 = ListPlot[{{2, 1}, {3, 4}, {3.5, 4.2}, {4, 6}, {4.5, 6.6}, {5, 
     7}, {6, 9}, {8, 11}}, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {Dotted}];

Legended[Show[g1, g2], 
 LineLegend[{Dashed, Dotted}, {"Dashed", "Dot"}]]
```

[image]